# IC on Breadboard: I have a PCB IC (LTC3115), how to search if it's available for breadboard use?

Tags: pcb-assembly

I am designing a PCB and am using buckboost converter IC - LTC3115. I have tested the component on the PCB and am not getting the required voltage output. My idea is now to check if it will work on a breadboard for the given configuration; how to check if the component is available on a breadboard? Digikey?

Alternatively, how will I know if my IC is burnt as that might be the issue why it's malfunctioning?

Comment: First, do not use breadboard for power application, it does not handle current well.

Answer (score 1):

> how to check if the component is available on a breadboard?

[Check the manufacturer's web site.](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc3115-1.html) The answer is "no"; this part is only available in surface-mount packages.

Switching power supply designs tend to be highly sensitive to layout. We may be able to provide advice if you can show us the design you're using.

Answer (score 0):

As @duskwuff suggested, switching power supply designs tend to be sensitive to layout. Since you haven't provided us with your design you could theoretically try [one of these](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1206) breakout boards to test the component on a breadboard. Keep in mind that breadboards are not designed to handle large current and/or large frequencies (typically > 10 MHz)